# Sync local mysql database and live server database?

Tags: mysql, php

Someone answer the question on the below but he did make it clear,
I can't see code where he connect to Database
how to combine the file (Footer.php, Config.php, Sync.php, sync_server.php)

Please I need solution onhow to sync local mysql database and live server database?

We don't always have internet. I want the application to run offline in 2 branches and update online database when there is internet.

please help me.

[how to sync local mysql database and live server database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74707/how-to-sync-local-mysql-database-and-live-server-database?rq=1)

Comment: Note I'm a developer working with php and mysql

Comment: Would it work for your "local" server to be a Slave to the "live" server (the Master)?